# PowerShell: Unable to use a variable variable $Using:(Get-Variable -Name $Name)

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, using, indirection, foreach-object

In a ForEach-Object -Parallel{}, I am trying to call variables with varying names defined prior to the function. This requires `$Using:Name` to pull in a variable from outside of the function.

However, when trying to use `$Using:$Name` or `$Using:(Get-Variable -Name $Name)` it provides an error: "Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name."

When trying to use `${Using:$Name}`, `{}` gives the literal string and does not work.
Other variations trying to make it work either provide the same variable reference is not valid or that the variable is null.

Variations tried:

```
$Using:{(Get-Variable -Name $Name)}
$Using:(Get-Variable -Name $Name)
Get-Variable -Name "Using:$Name"
Get-Variable -Name Using:$Name
```

Code Example:

```
$0IndexA = @(45,51,57)
$1IndexA = @(1490,1901,1903)

0..1 | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
    $ParallelNumber = $_ # Used for readability

    For ($c = 0; $c -le (Get-Variable $ParallelNumber"IndexA").value.count; $c++){
        Get-Variable -Name $ParallelNumber"IndexA"[$c]
    }
}
```

Error: Cannot find a variable with the name '0IndexA'.

Trying with -scope 1
Error:"The scope number '1' exceeds the number of active scopes. (Parameter 'Scope') Actual value was 1."

Comment: Where is `$Name` defined? Please share code that reproduces the issue :)

Comment: 0..1 | ForEach-Object <#-ThrottleLimit 5#> -Parallel {
    $Name = ([string]($Using:1IndexA[1])+"A")
    $Using:(Get-Variable -Name $Name)
}

$Using:1IndexA[1])+"A" - This successfully returns the string "1901A" for testing.

Yes, I know the code above is not utilizing the ForEach-Object component, I have a larger function for it, but this is where the error lies.

Comment: I think I get what your problem is, not sure if what you want to do can be done, but you might try accessing a HashTable through using instead: `$HashVars = @{a = 123; b = 234; c = 345}; 'a', 'b', 'c' | Foreach-Object -Parallel { ($using:HashVars)[$_] }`

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible code. Your code above in the comment doesnt make any since.

Comment: The syntax for ```$using``` is ```$using:<VariableName>```, not ```$using:<expression>``` - it needs a bare variable name, not an expression that evaluates to a string that contains a variable name - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.3#using-local-variables. If you need to reference values by expression you can use @Darin's suggestion of a hashtable as a workaround...

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for ***variable indirection***, i.e. the ability to refer to a variable *indirectly*, via its name stored in *another* variable.

However, **in the context of the [`$using:`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) scope this is *not* supported**: what follows `:` *must* be a *literal* variable name.

As [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190564/darin) suggests, a **workaround** is to use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) in the caller's scope that maps the input objects to the values to be used for them:

```bash
# Helper hashtable that maps each input to ForEach-Object -Parallel
# to values to use with that input.
$valuesHash = @{
  0 = @(45,51,57)
  1 = @(1490,1901,1903)
}

0..1 | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
  $values = ($using:valuesHash)[$_]
  "$values" # sample output; -> '45 51 57', '1490 1901 1903'
}
```

Note the need to enclose the `$using:` reference in `(...)` in order to apply an index (`[$_]`) to it.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Arguably, this shouldn't be necessary, but is as of PowerShell 7.3.9 - see [GitHub issue #10876](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10876) for a discussion.</sup>

Comment: FYI: Since he is using numeric values, an Array of arrays is also an option: `$IndexA = @(@(45,51,57), @(1490,1901,1903)); 0..1 | Foreach-Object -Parallel { $ParallelNumber = $_; For ($c = 0; $c -le ($Using:IndexA)[$_].Count; $c++) { ($Using:IndexA)[$_][$c] } }`

Comment: Good point, Darin, but that is a very specific scenario (contiguous numbers starting with `0` as input). By contrast, the hashtable-based approach should work with any input objects.

Answer (score 0):

@mkelement answer seems like a good solution. In case that doesn't work for you , another workaround is to use jobs instead of `Foreach-Object -Parallel`, that way you can pass the variables as input arguments.

I have re-worked your sample to demonstrate:

```
$0IndexA = @(45,51,57)
$1IndexA = @(1490,1901,1903)


$parJobs = 0..1 | foreach {
    Start-Job { 
    Param($0IndexA, $1IndexA, $ParallelNumber)
        For ($c = 0; $c -le (Get-Variable "$($ParallelNumber)IndexA").value.count; $c++){
            (Get-Variable -Name "$($ParallelNumber)IndexA").value[$c]
        }
    } -ArgumentList $0IndexA,$1IndexA, $_
} 

Wait-Job $parJobs | Receive-Job
```